# 2D Array, using get method on a element that is Null, is there an elegant solution?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

How do I check if an element is null in a 2D ArrayList, without a null pointer exception?
For clarity i will define the following:

```
List<String> innerList = new ArrayList()<>;
List<List<String> outerList = new ArrayList()<>;
```

I want to use .get() on on the outer list to pull an inner list.
The issue is that as soon as I use the .get() method on a null element it gives a null pointer exception.
My Goal is to check if an element in the outerList is null if so then do something. If it is not null do something else. I cannot check if the element is null because i have to use the .get() since it is 2D, which is my current issue.
Example code:

```
List<List<String>> outerList = new ArrayList()<>;


    if(outerList.get(indexOfANullElement).isEmpty()){
        //do something...
    }
```

as soon as the .get() method is used on a null element it automatically gives me a null pointer. I cant wrap it because I would have to first refer to the secondary list with a .get() which would automatically return null.

Comment: Java doesn't have multidimensional arrays and furthermore what you have doesn't use arrays at all. However if you wish to approximate a two dimensional structure initialize it as such and you won't have this problem

Comment: it is initilized as a 2D structure. the issue is that for me to access or do anything with an innerList, i need to first use the .get() method, but if the element happens to be null, it will immedialty give the null pointer exception.

Comment: I think you really want to read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. It is pretty unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with

```
List<String> innerList = outerList.get(index);
if (innerList == null)
```

Meaning: before calling a method on the retrieved list, you can easily check if it is null.

For more specific advice we will need to see more of your code.

Comment: If I use outerList.get(index) on an element that doesnt exist in the outer list it will just return null. as soon as I try to get something that is null there will be an exception

Comment: @Derevi, you should be able to call the .get(index) method on an element even if it is null. This answer checks if the inner list is null, and you can now safely call the get method of the inner list. If you get a null pointer exception when executing "outerList.get(index)" then that doesn't mean that your element is null, but it means that "outerList" is null.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error from `primaryList.get(indexOfSecondayList)` this statement as the **size** of `primaryList` is **0**. So the correct approach to avoid this error is

```
List<List<String>> outerList = new ArrayList()<>;

if (outerList.size() > 0) {
   List<String> innerList = outerList.get(index);
}
```

Comment: Important to note that this question specifically states that the code throws a NullPointerException. If the issue were that outerList/primaryList is 0, then it would throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Furthermore, if you wished to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException, then you would need to check that the index < outerList.size(), not that outerList.size() > 0 as it doesn't ensure that your index is in bounds.

Comment: It is very prominent that if you give an abnormal index to access `outList` then you surely get another exception. **However**, `outerList.get(indexOfANullElement)` this line will never give _NullPointerException_ as it is initialized just before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Minor modification to your code which would work like a charm

```
if(primaryList.get(indexOfSecondaryList) != null 
   && primaryList.get(indexOfSecondaryList).isEmpty()){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: the issue is that using the .get() method on an element that is null will instantly return null exception and i need the .get() method to access the secondary list

Comment: Think is your outerList is not null. Because you have defined it with new keyword. So calling outerList.get() will not result in NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is not necessary but it assures you will only access members of outerList if they exist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < outerList.size(); i++) {
    List innerList = outerList.get(i);
    if (innerList != null)
        // rest of code    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think you're confusing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with `NullPointerException`.

```
List<String> samples = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    System.out.println(samples.get(0)); // throw IndexOutOfBoundsException 
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Thread.sleep(200); // just wait for the err to print to the console first before the out
samples.add(null);
System.out.println(samples.get(0)); // works fine
```

So think in your code, you might want to check the list's `size` with the `index` first.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 there is the alternative way to deal with `null`: `Optional`. We can use `Optional.filter` to check different conditions:

```
int index = 0;
Optional<List<String>> outerListElementAtIndex = Optional.of(outerList).filter(l -> l.size() > index).map(l -> l.get(index));
```

Basically it chceks if the index is valid regarding the length of the list. Having such an `Optinal` you can continue to access an element of the inner list in the same way:

```
int innerElementIndex = 0;
Optional<String> optionalString = outerListElementAtIndex.filter(l -> l.size() > index).map(l -> l.get(innerElementIndex));
```

We can wrap the code to a helper method:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> getOptionalElementAtIndexes(List<List<T>> list, int outerIndex, int innerIndex) {
    return Optional.of(list)
            .filter(l -> l.size() > outerIndex).map(l -> l.get(outerIndex))
            .filter(l -> l.size() > innerIndex).map(l -> l.get(innerIndex));
}
```

Then we get an `Optinal<String>` with one line:

```
Optional<String> optionalString = getOptionalElementAtIndexes(outerList, outerIndex, innertIndex);
```

This way we make sure to get an element of any `List` only if the list is not `null` and has enough elements. As you asked: Is this "*an elegent solution*"?